# Acyclic extension of free DGA-modules

Tags: homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras

I want to find some method to do the following: given an DGA-module $M$
over some commutative ring $k$, positively graded ($M_i=0$ if $i<0$), where each component $M_i$ has a free action by the symmetric group $\mathbb{S}_i$, 
and $k$-free, then there is an acyclic DGA-module $N$ extending $M$  ($M\subset N$), with $N_0=M_0$ and also with free actions by the symmetric groups and $k$-free in each degree.
I think it is possible and probably someone already do it, but i can't find 
articles or books talking about it. I know there are methods to construct free resolutions of modules(which correspond to the case when $M_i=0$ for $i>0$).
Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with the cone?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but i don't see the relation.

Comment: I mean the standard inclusion into the cone $M\subset CM$. What fails with this? Am I missing something?

Comment: The problem is that $CM$ is not acyclic, it is free and $H_*(CM)=0$, but $N$ needs to have the homology of a point.

Comment: For me, acyclic means trivial homology.